# Optimize mathematical expressions

Tags: c++, c, optimization

I am frustrated with how much time the fitch software take to do some simple computations. I profiled it with Intel VTune and it seems that 52% of the CPU time is spent in the `nudists()` function:

```
void nudists(node *x, node *y)
{
  /* compute distance between an interior node and tips */
  long nq=0, nr=0, nx=0, ny=0;
  double dil=0, djl=0, wil=0, wjl=0, vi=0, vj=0;
  node *qprime, *rprime;

  qprime = x->next;
  rprime = qprime->next->back;
  qprime = qprime->back;
  ny = y->index;
  dil = qprime->d[ny - 1];
  djl = rprime->d[ny - 1];
  wil = qprime->w[ny - 1];
  wjl = rprime->w[ny - 1];
  vi = qprime->v;
  vj = rprime->v;
  x->w[ny - 1] = wil + wjl;
  if (wil + wjl <= 0.0)
    x->d[ny - 1] = 0.0;
  else
    x->d[ny - 1] = ((dil - vi) * wil + (djl - vj) * wjl) / (wil + wjl);
  nx = x->index;
  nq = qprime->index;
  nr = rprime->index;
  dil = y->d[nq - 1];
  djl = y->d[nr - 1];
  wil = y->w[nq - 1];
  wjl = y->w[nr - 1];
  y->w[nx - 1] = wil + wjl;
  if (wil + wjl <= 0.0)
    y->d[nx - 1] = 0.0;
  else
    y->d[nx - 1] = ((dil - vi) * wil + (djl - vj) * wjl) / (wil + wjl);
}  /* nudists */
```

The two long lines are responsible for 24% of the total CPU time. Is there any way to optimize this code and especially the two long lines? Another function which consumes a lot of CPU time is this:

```
void secondtraverse(node *q, double y, long *nx, double *sum)
{
  /* from each of those places go back to all others */
   /* nx comes from firsttraverse */
   /* sum comes from evaluate via firsttraverse */
  double z=0.0, TEMP=0.0;

  z = y + q->v;
  if (q->tip) {
    TEMP = q->d[(*nx) - 1] - z;
    *sum += q->w[(*nx) - 1] * (TEMP * TEMP);
  } else {
    secondtraverse(q->next->back, z, nx, sum);
    secondtraverse(q->next->next->back, z, nx,sum);
  }
}  /* secondtraverse */
```

The code which calculates the sum is responsible for 18% of the CPU time. Any way to make it run faster?

The complete source code can be found here: http://evolution.genetics.washington.edu/phylip/getme.html

Comment: Off topic, but why is your function called `nudists`?

Comment: Outside of improving Big O for an algorithm, optimization can be something of a dark art.  The correct approach is usually *modify, profile, repeat*.  If you can read the disassembly, all the better.  You can eliminate if/else branching here with some bit trickery.  You can eliminate redundant divisions by precalculating `1.0 / (wil + wjl)`.

Comment: I don't know - it isn't me who has written the software. This is open source.

Comment: Correction - the two `/ (wil + wjl)` divisions are *not* redundant.  That was an oversight on my part.

Comment: The values of `wil` and `wjl` change between the two computations:

Comment: why was this question downvoted, is it not a valid question ?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: No, grabbing a random piece of code you didn't write and do not understand and asking to have someone else optimize it is not valid.  The downvote arrow says "this question shows little research effort", which seems to be the case.  OP hasn't made any attempt at solving his own problem (although identifying the hot spot was a good step)

Comment: I think, your best hope would be to reduce the number of calls to these functions, there seems to be little optimization potential in them. You might achieve some optimization by unrolling the iteration in `secondtraverse()` to reduce the number of function calls, but that's all I can see.

Comment: @BenVoigt not sure if I agree if he ran it through a profiler and was able to pinpoint this function as culplrit amongst a zillion other functions I would say that this shows research effort. But I can be wrong, if he just took it from that link...

Comment: What compiler are you using?  What were the optimization settings when you performed profiling?

Comment: What processor are you using?  What floating point processor?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: But that still doesn't make it his code.  When asking a question, the OP is expected to be able to explain the purpose and algorithm used by the code under discussion, and that's not happening here.

Comment: I've tried both gcc-4.8.2 and icc 13. ICC produces a bit faster code. I am running on Intel Core i5-2320, Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I compile with `-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as optimizing the big equation lines, you are using some of the most time consuming operations:  multiplication and division.

You will have to look for optimizations in a bigger frame, picture or scope.  Some ideas:

- Fixed Point arithmetic
- Eliminating the division for each iteration.
- Threading
- Mulitple cores
- Array, not linked list

### Fixed Point Arithmetic

If you can make your numeric base a power of 2, many of your divisions will change into bit shifts.  For example, dividing by 16 is the same as right shifting 4 times.  Shifts are usually faster than divisions.

### Eliminating division per iteration

Rather than performing the division on each iteration, extract it out and perform it less often, perhaps using different values.

If you treat the division as a fraction, you can play with the numerator many times before dividing by the denominator.

### Threading

You may want to consider multiple threads.  Create threads based on code efficiency.  Let one thread be a worker thread that calculates in the background.

### Multiple Cores (parallel execution)

The 'x' and 'y' variables appear to be independent of each other.  These calculations could be set up for parallel programming.  One core or processor performs the 'x' calculation while another core is calculating the 'y' variable.

Think about splitting this at a higher level.  One core (thread) processes all the 'x' variables while another core processes the 'y' variables.  The results saved independently.  Let the main core process all the results after all the 'x' and 'y' variables have been calculated.

### Arrays, not lists

Your processor will be happiest when all its data can fit into the processor's data cache.  If it can't fit all the data, then fit as much as possible.  Thus arrays will have the best chance of fitting into a data cache line than a linked list.  The processor will know that an array address sequential and may not have to reload the data cache.